# Can't download tar.gz file with curl from putty : EC2

Tags: linux, curl, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am accessing my EC2 instance via putty (for the first time) and I am trying to download and install the NLTK package.

Following this example: http://gavinmhackeling.com/blog/2012/03/deploying-a-python-nltk-django-app-to-amazon-ec2/

I use: `curl -O http://nltk.googlecode.com/files/nltk-2.0b7.tar.gz`

and instead i just get "Putty Putty Putty.......Putty" output to the the terminal screen and i have to `CTRL C` to get back to the command prompt.

I'm new to EC2 what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens if you try the following?

```
wget http://nltk.googlecode.com/files/nltk-2.0b7.tar.gz
```